# Problem with Clamping Values for Object's Rotation - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, rotation

I'm having trouble clamping the barrel's degrees plus its parent's(the tank's hull) degrees as well so I can get the same result like it does right of the picture below.

So the script is simple it rotates the barrel(**turretBarrel**) with the Y_Mouse Input and rotates the upperPart(**turret**) of the tank with the X_Mouse Input, along with barrel stabilization.
**Script**

```
   //Note this.transform is the tanks hull
  public Transform turret;
  public Transform turretBarrel;
  float xRot;
  float angleY;
  float rotY;
  float minTurretRotY;
  float maxTurretRotY;
  Vector3 mRot;
  Vector3 rot;


  public void Update(){
            xRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 0.5f;
            turret.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(turret.transform.localRotation.x, xRot, turret.transform.localRotation.z);

            angleY -= Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * 0.5f;
            angleY = Mathf.Clamp(angleY, minTurretRotY, maxTurretRotY);

            mRot = turret.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            rot = turretBarrel.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            rotY = angleY;
            rotY = Mathf.Clamp(rotY, minTurretRotY, maxTurretRotY);

            // I'm using Quaternion.Euler for barrel Stabilization
            turretBarrel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(rotY, mRot.y, mRot.z));
            //Debug.Log(rotY +"  |  " + angleY + "/ Min : " + minTurretRotY+ " ;  Max : " + (maxTurretRotY));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `mrot = turret.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;` instead.

Comment: that does not work.

Comment: I don't really get what you are doing in the code. Does the model have a correct hierarchy? If so, it would be sufficient to just store the two angles (and update them upon input) and set the two rotations of turret and barrel to be pure rotations about the corresponding axis (probably y and x).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the min and max Y according to the Y rotation of the main body(tank) also. Update like this:

```
minY = YRotationOfParent;
maxY = YRotationOfParent + someOffSet;
```